# Is there a database of disease prevalence?

Tags: database, public-databases

I want to collect data on how common different diseases are in different populations (or, at least, globally). Ideally, it would give me a way of querying the database with a disease name, and would return the number of cases per N population.

My main objective is to have a general idea of how prevalent a disease is, I am not trying to track current outbreaks, so I am not too bothered if the information is a little out of date, as long as the database is still maintained and not abandoned.

I have found [FIDD](https://medicapps.cardiff.ac.uk/fidd/about.aspx), but it seems to be no longer maintained. Are there any actively maintained, similar tools that have the information I am after?

Answer (score 5):

For rare diseases, you can use [Orphanet](http://www.orpha.net/consor/cgi-bin/Disease_Search.php?lng=EN). You can download an xml file with prevalence from [orphadata](http://www.orpha.net/consor/cgi-bin/index.php?lng=EN).

There is an OWL version of Orphanet called [ORDO](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/ontologies/ordo), you can browse it on the EBI Ontology Lookup Service. See for example [Arrhythmogenic right ventricular cardiomyopathy](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/ontologies/ordo/terms?iri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.orpha.net%2FORDO%2FOrphanet_247) and point prevalence relationships in the lower right box. There are a variety of programmatic ways to access this, including the OLS web API, SPARQL queries, or downloading the OWL and using an ontology API.

Answer (score 5):

Comment as an answer, as requested.

The [Incidence and Prevalance Database](http://www.tdrdata.com/ipd/ipd_init) (IPD - subscription required).